# Antisymmetric polynomials in two variables

Tags: functions, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, skew-symmetric-matrices

In [Prove that every symmetric polynomial can be written in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663453/prove-that-every-symmetric-polynomial-can-be-written-in-terms-of-the-elementary) it is argued that a symmetric polynomial of two variables $x,y$ can be written as a sum over terms of the form $(x+y)^m (xy)^n$, for $m,n \ge0$ integers.

Is there anything similar for antisymmetric polynomials in two variables? I would like to have one (or many equivalent) parametrization in terms of elementary antisymmetric "blocks" like $x+y$, $xy$ in the symmetric case. Of course, such parametrization should give the most general antisymmetric polynomial for a given order.

One such block could be given for example by $(x-y)^m$ for odd integers $m$, in turn multiplied by any $x,y$ symmetric term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y)$ is an anti-symmetric polynomial, then the polynomial $x-y$ divides $f$, and $f$ can be written as $(x-y)g(x,y)$, where $g$ is a symmetric polynomial. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805213/), for example, for a generalization to $n$ variables.) So, using the characterization of symmetric polynomials, any anti-symmetric polynomial can be written as a linear combination of polynomials of the form
$$(x-y)(x+y)^m(xy)^n$$
for integers $m,n\geq 0$.

Comment: What is it meant by "divide"?

Comment: @Rubilax96 A polynomial $P$ divides another polynomial $Q$ if we can write $Q=P\cdot R$ for some polynomial $R$.